# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module | React Native

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm trying to run tests on my React Native project, and when I run the test script, it throws an error as below

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/polyfills/babelHelpers.js:3
    import _typeof from "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:70:6)
```

**`package.json`**

```json
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.7.4",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "9.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.14",
    "@types/react-navigation": "1.5.9",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.20.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.8.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "husky": "^1.0.0-rc.14",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^2.1.2",
    "jest-serializer-enzyme": "^1.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react": ">=16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-render-html": "4.1.1",
    "react-navigation": "2.18.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  },

...

  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base|react-navigation|react-native-fabric|static-container|@shoutem|lottie-react-native)",
      "/@babel/runtime/",
      "//core-js/"
    ],
    "automock": false,
    "bail": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 0,
        "branches": 0,
        "lines": 0,
        "functions": 0
      }
    },
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "text"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./__tests__/config/coverage",
    "cacheDirectory": "./__tests__/config/cache",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/__tests__/config",
      "/__tests__/config/*",
      "/__tests__/__mocks__",
      "/__tests__/__mocksResponse__",
      "/__tests__/__constants__",
      "node_modules",
      ".history"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.test.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./__tests__/config/setup.js"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./__tests__/config/setup.js"
    ]
  },
```

**`babel.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['transform-remove-console'],
    },
    test: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', 'react-native', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-classes',
        '@babel/syntax-class-properties',
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'],
};
```

I already added `"type": "module"` to my package.json, but then I got the following error:

````
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/{user_name}/{project_name}/babel.config.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /Users/{user_name}/{project_name}/babel.config.js from /Users/{user_name}/{project_name}/node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.

Instead rename babel.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/{user_name}/{project_name}/package.json.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using **type="module"** in your **package.json**, the error message indicates that the file *babel.config.js* is being treated as an ES module. However, the *babel-jest* library, the one trying to load the *babel.config.js*, doesn't support loading ES modules as config files.

I suggest the following options to resolve this:

1. Rename *babel.config.js* to *babel.config.cjs* to indicate that it's a CommonJS module. The *.cjs* extension indicates that it is a CommonJS module, which can be loaded using **require()**. This change will allow *babel-jest* to properly load the configuration.
2. Use separate configuration files, such as *babel.config.js* for CommonJS syntax and *babel.config.mjs* for ES6 syntax. Remove **type: "module"** from **package.json** and update the Babel configuration accordingly.